# If $A$ is countably infinite and $R$ is a partial order on $A$, then $R$ can be extended to a total order

Tags: problem-solving, order-theory

I'm really looking for advice on how to solve this problem, rather than the solution.

I know why any poset on a finite set has a linear extension:
It's obviously true for sets of size $0,1$ and $2$. If you have a poset on a set of size $2$, when you add a 3rd element, you add some new ordered pairs in the poset. Since you already know it holds for sets of size $2$, you can remove a minimal element and get a total order on the other $2$ elements. Then since the element that was removed is minimal, it's easy to build a total order on the entire set (let the minimal element be smaller than everything else in the total order).

So now you know that it holds for any set of size $3$, and you can easily repeat this for sets of size $4$, remove a minimal element, get a total order on the other $3$ elements and construct a total order on all $4$ elements by letting the minimal element be smaller than everything.

This strategy works for any cardinality $n$, and that's why the proof is done by induction.

The problem I have right now is that for infinitely countable sets, you can't use this strategy, you cant reach infinity by repeatedly adding $1$ element. There's no guarantee of a minimal element either. What should I do at this point? Should I try to find an answer to the question:

> Why is it not possible to have a poset on a countably infinite set
> that cant be extended to a linear order?

I often see people say that if you are struggling with proving something, you should really understand why the theorem must actually be true.

Comment: What a non-total order has that a total order doesn't are incomparable elements. There are at most $|A|^2$ of those. So, you can do induction on the incomparable pairs. If you pick one pair of incomparable elements, you can impose an order between them in any way you want. It is not going to contradict the already existing edges, since the partial order was transitive already. Inserting that edge can break transitivity due to missing edges, though. So, you need to take the transitive closure of the result. And then repeat with a new pair that is still incomparable.

Comment: but doesnt $|A|^2=\aleph_0^2=\aleph_0$? How can you induct on that?

Comment: How do you do induction on $\mathbb{N}$, that has $|\mathbb{N}|=\aleph_0$.

Comment: @NDB what do you mean by "its not going to contradict already existing edges, since the partial order was transitive already"

Comment: Assume that $a\succ_{original} b$ and $b\succ_{original} a$ are not true. In other words, $a$ and $b$ are not comparable. Introducing the edge $a\succ_{new} b$ could cause a problem if there were a path $b\succ_{original} b_1\succ_{original}...\succ_{original} b_n\succ_{original} a$. But no such path exists, because transitivity would have imposed that $b\succ_{original} a$ already existed.

Comment: Of course, once you introduce $a\succ_{new}b$ transitivity might be broken, but due to edges that are missing. For example, if $b\succ_{original}c$ and $a\succ_{original}c$ doesn't exist in the order. Or if $d\succ_{original}a$, but $d\succ_{original}b$ doesn't exist. All of those missing, but now required, edges need to be added, together with $a\succ_{new}b$. That is called, taking [transitive closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_closure).

Comment: @NDB How would I use induction? I can't induct on the amount of incomparable pairs right? How would induction on the incomparable pairs work? Also is axiom of choice required for this?

Comment: Let $A_0$ be the initial set of sets $\{a,b\}$ of two elements with $a,b$ incomparable. Fix an enumeration of $A_0$. The argument above shows that we can impose some order to the first pair of elements in that enumeration. We can then take transitive closure, which might impose some order to other pairs that were incomparable. Let $A_1\subsetneq A_0$ be the new set of incomparables with the order induced by the enumeration of $A_0$. Suppose that we have already defined $A_n\subsetneq...\subsetneq A_0$.

Comment: Define $A_{n+1}$ by imposing some order to the first pair in $A_n$ and those imposed by the transitive closure. Use induction to show that $\bigcap_n A_n=\emptyset$. The induction is kind of trivial. $A_0\supset\bigcap_n A_n$. The $0$-th element of $A_0$ is not in $\bigcap_n A_n$. Assume that the $k$-th element of $A_0$ is not in $\bigcap_n A_n$, for all $k<n$. Then the $n$-th element is not in $\bigcap_n A_n$. It was removed at least in $A_n$. Induction gives that all elements of $A_0$ are not in $\bigcap_n A_n$. So, this is empty.